# How to remove broken video tags from all Wordpress content

Tags: database, wordpress, video, phpmyadmin, tags

I have a wordpress website with more than 3000 posts. Many of my old posts contains video tags of few websites that already shutdown ( Putlocker, Sockshare )

I was using a plugin to embed their video inside my post. ( eg: [sockshare]zygu5ya9xq9u[/sockshare] ,[putlocker]hnd5yatsq9m[/putlocker]  ). Each post contains different video id.

Now I want to remove these tags from my old posts. Is there any phpmyadmin query that I can replace/remove? Or any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

First backup your all you DB to avoid mistakes and maybe try this locally and see if it works properly.
You could go into your php my admin and under the SQL tab and insert a query like:

```
  UPDATE wp_posts
  SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content,
                 SUBSTRING(post_content, 
                           INSTR(post_content,'[sockshare]'), 
                           INSTR(post_content,'[/sockshare]') -INSTR(post_content,'[sockshare]')
                          )
                 ,'')
```

do the same for [putlocker]